# Empty line number when removing date

Tags: line-numbering, linenumber, empty-line

I have line numbers displayed and no date after the title. However, if I remove the date with
`\date{}`
there is a line number left in the empty line after the title. How can I remove it?

Here is the minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{The title}
\author{}

\usepackage{lineno}
\linenumbers

\date{} % clear date

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section*{Section 1}
Text

\end{document}
```

[image: Empty line number]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Are you sure that the blank line is caused by `\date{}`? To me, it looks like it's caused by `\author{}`. Try replacing `\author{}` with, say, `\author{.}` to see what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

First off: Greetings from a Star Wars fan to a Pulp Fiction fan! :-)

You wrote,

> However, if I remove the date with `\date{}` there is a line number left in the empty line after the title. How can I remove it?

Actually, the cause of the problem is not `\date{}`, but `\author{}`. This may be verified by redefining the `\@maketitle` command to remove the six lines of code that typeset the contents of the `\author` directive:

```
\makeatletter  % code obtained from 'article.cls'
\renewcommand\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
  \begin{center}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
%    {\large
%      \lineskip .5em%
%      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
%        \@author
%      \end{tabular}\par}%
%    \vskip 1em%
    {\large \@date}%
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \vskip 1.5em}
\makeatother
```

If you place this code chunk in the preamble, you'll get the following output despite the presence of `\date{}`:

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you.